# Effective thread-safe Java List impl when traversals match mutations

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a number of threads that will be consuming messages from a broker and processing them. Each message is XML containing, amongst other elements, an alpha-numeric `<itemId>WI354DE48</itemId>` element that serves as a unique ID for the item to "process". Due to criteria I can't control or change, it is possible for items/messages to be duplicated on the broker queue that thhese threads are consuming from. So the same item (with an ID of WI354DE48), might only be sent to the queue once, or it might get sente 100 times. Regardless, I can only allow the item to be processed once; so I need a way to prevent Thread A from processing a duplicated item that Thread B already processed.

I'm looking to use a simple thread-safe list that can be shared by all threads (workers) to act as a cache mechanism. Each thread will be given the same instance of a `List<String>`. When each worker thread consumes a message, it checks to see if the `itemId` (a String) exists on the list. If it doesn't then no other worker has processed the item. In this case, the `itemID` is added to the list (locking/caching it), and then the item is processed. If the `itemId` does already exist on the list, then another worker has already processed the item, so we can ignore it. Simple, yet effective.

It's obviously then paramount to have a thread-safe list implementation. Note that the only two methods we will ever be calling on this list will be:

- `List#contains(String)` - traversing/searching the list
- `List#add(String)` - mutating the list

...and its important to note that we will be calling both methods with about the same frequency. Only rarely will `contains()` return `true` and prevent us from needing to `add` the ID.

I first thought that `CopyOnWriteArrayList` was my best bet, but after reading the Javadocs, it seems like each worker would just wind up with its own thread-local copy of the list, which isn't what I want. I then looked into `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>)`, and that seems to be a decent bet:

```
List<String> processingCache = Collection.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
List<Worker> workers = getWorkers(processingCache); // Inject the same list into all workers.
for(Worker worker : workers)
    executor.submit(worker);

// Inside each Worker's run method:
@Override
public void run() {
    String itemXML = consumeItemFromBroker();
    Item item = toItem(itemXML);

    if(processingCache.contains(item.getId())
        return;
    else
        processingCache.add(item.getId());

    ... continue processing.
}
```

Am I on track with `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>)`, or am I way off base? Is there a more efficient thread-safe `List` impl given my use case, and if so, why?

Comment: Looks like you need a `Set` instead of a `List`, basically for this sentence: *Only rarely will contains() return true and prevent us from needing to add the ID*. It would be better to use [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedList` is very basic, it just marks all methods as `synchronized`.

This will work but only under some specific assumptions, namely that you never carry out multiple accesses to the `List`, i.e.

```
if(!list.contains(x))
    list.add(x);
```

Is **not** thread safe as the monitor is released between the two calls.

It can also be somewhat slow if you have many reads and few writes as all threads acquire an exclusive lock.

You can look at the implementations in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, there are several options.

I would recommend using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) with dummy values.

The reason for the recommendation is that the `ConcurrentHashMap` has synchronized key groups so if you have a good hashing algorithm (and `String` does) you can actually get a massive amount of concurrent throughput.

I would prefer this over a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` as it doesn't guarantee ordering and therefore you lose that overhead.

Of course with threading it's never entirely obvious where the bottlenecks are so I would suggest trying both and seeing which gives you better performance.

Comment: Thanks @Boris the Spider (+1) - can you weigh-in with Luiggi Mendoza's suggestion for `ConcurrentSkipListSet`? Performance-wise, how would it fair with `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: @TicketMonster it will depend on your needs. Do some tests and decide by yourself. There's no exact answer on this except that you must use a `Set` instead of a `List`.